# Apache2 - 400 bad request while accessing using docker service name but works with IP address

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, apache2.4

I'm deploying stack with `docker stack deploy`. In this stack there is nginx as reverse proxy and  apache2 as backend server.

Now If I access my apache2 container from other container using `curl -v http://service_name:8888` it returns 400 bad request error. But if i try `curl -v 10.0.9.7:8888` it works with 200 success code.

I am not able to pinpoint where is the error.

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ServerAdmin admin@sa.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/site"

  ServerName r.sa.com
  <Directory /var/www/site>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 8888
Listen 8889

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**error.log**

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log 
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.0.9. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Mar 05 07:17:41.921722 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 05 07:17:41.922504 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: "400 bad request error" seems as if http://service_name:8888 were attended by some service with SSL and receive plain text in request. Can you add some logs?.

Comment: @matiferrigno added error.log of apache

Comment: could you add access/error log of apache and nginx reverse proxy logs in the time lapse that you do both curl?

Comment: Can you add to stack.yml too ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache blocked HTTP requests with an underscore ("_") as the hostname. If you change your service name to "service-name" it will work.

Reference: https://ma.ttias.be/apache-httpd-2-2-15-60-underscores-hostnames-now-blocked/